# Pixlr Editor Popup is not hiding in Exit

Tags: javascript, popup, editor

Why pixlr editor popup is not hiding while clicking on exit button, instead it loads content of the of exit URL page in the popup itself.   Please refer the image.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pixlr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    pixlr.settings.target = 'http://localhost/pix/index.php';
    pixlr.settings.exit = 'http://localhost/pix/index.php';
    pixlr.settings.credentials = false;
    pixlr.settings.method = 'GET';
    pixlr.settings.method = 'SFA Customizer';
    pixlr.settings.locktarget = true;
    pixlr.settings.redirect = true;
    pixlr.settings.locktype = 'png';
    pixlr.settings.wmode = true;
</script>
```

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this close issue i had added small  fix i.e. i had added small close button on the top right corner as well as i had documented this in the following link.

http://www.smarttutorials.net/integrate-pixlr-online-photo-editor-web-application/